# Set dropdown field value in Power apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, dropdown, powerapp

I have a drop-down field in my form, I am using below code on select:

```
DataCardValue7.Selected.Value= "9:00 AM"
```

Also tried with passing variable:

```
DataCardValue7.Selected.Value= varTime
```

Comment: Do you want to set default value of drop-down? Or set value of drop-down on selection of other control?

Comment: yes, setting dropdown value when other control is selected

Comment: Try creating a variable and then set its value on change of first control and use this variable as default value for your dropdown.

Answer (score 3):

Try below steps:

1. Create one variable in PowerApps. Let Say, `Testvariable`.
2. **OnChange** of your first control, Update the value of this variable like:

   `UpdateContext({Testvariable: Dropdown1.Selected.Value})`
3. Then Set **Default** property of your second drop-down with this variable.

**Reference**:

[Change dropdown value OnSelect](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Change-dropdown-value-OnSelect/td-p/126854).

Comment: Hi KumarV does this answers your question? If yes, Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that it will help others with same question to find the correct answer easily. It also removes the question from "Unanswered questions" list.